Getting undefined in the download url while fetching the RFI attachments using the attachment endpoint
I am working on the Autodesk integration and I need to fetch the RFIs and their attachments and download them using the API. I am able to get the RFIs and their attachments but the API returns "undefined" in the URL attachments response and when I use that URL to generate the signed s3 key it returns me "invalid bucket" in the response which causes an issue in downloading the file. Can anyone provide me with the solution or tell me if I am missing something? This is the response I am getting:
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "b7e0fe26-48bd-42de-b23a-043702edd251",
            "name": "#1 - Test RFI-202405290943.pdf",
            "urn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:t-D-Jki9Qt6yOgQ3Au3SUQ",
            "urnType": "oss",
            "createdBy": "YUN2FW7UKAT4LDRB",
            "createdAt": "2024-05-30T11:06:36.000Z",
            "deletedBy": null,
            "deletedAt": null,
            "permittedActions": {
                "removeAttachment": true
            },
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/t-D-Jki9Qt6yOgQ3Au3SUQ/objects/undefined"
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "limit": 10,
        "offset": 0,
        "totalResults": 1
    }
}

This is the response I am getting:
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "b7e0fe26-48bd-42de-b23a-043702edd251",
            "name": "#1 - Test RFI-202405290943.pdf",
            "urn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:t-D-Jki9Qt6yOgQ3Au3SUQ",
            "urnType": "oss",
            "createdBy": "YUN2FW7UKAT4LDRB",
            "createdAt": "2024-05-30T11:06:36.000Z",
            "deletedBy": null,
            "deletedAt": null,
            "permittedActions": {
                "removeAttachment": true
            },
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/t-D-Jki9Qt6yOgQ3Au3SUQ/objects/undefined"
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "limit": 10,
        "offset": 0,
        "totalResults": 1
    }
}


Unfortunately, this is a known issue that has been logged with the internal ticket:
SCPJM-21556:[APIs Support] GET Attachments return undefined url for existing Document from the visible folders
I appended this Stackoverflow post to that ticket.
